# How can i list all Items that belongs to all the Subcategories of a certain Category? ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, relationship, categories

Here are my models relationships:

- `Category has_many Subcategories`
- `Subcategory belongs_to Category` (`Subcategories` has a `category_id` field)
- `Subcategory has_many items`
- `Item belongs_to Subcategory` (`Items` has a `subcategory_id` field)

I want to list all items belonging to the subcategories of a certain category in the show view of Category.

For example in the Food category that has restaurant, fast food and delivery subcategories. 
I would like to show all the items in the 3 subcategories in the show view of the food category.

I have problems with the condition to make this possible:

```
<%@items = Item.find(:all, :limit=> 10, :conditions {:subcategory_id =>  }, :order=>"created_at ASC")%>
        <%@items .each do |items|%>
Items info shown here
<% end %>
```

I don't know if I have to make it through a condition, by an `if` statement or maybe a helper method.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how i solve it.

i save in a variable @subcategory_id the comparision between the subcategory.category_id and the category.id

```
<%@subcategory_id = Subcategory.find(:all, :conditions => {:category_id => @category.id}, :order=>"created_at ASC")%>
```

and then i use that variable to make the condition in the query of the items list

```
<%@lastitems= Item.find(:all, :conditions => {:subcategory_id => @subcategory_id}, :order=>"created_at ASC")%>
        <%@lastitems.each do |lastitem|%>


items info goes here

<%end%>
```

Thanks.